# Euler vs. Hamiltonian path or circuit for a bus route

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Let's say that we have to pick up and drop off children at different stops along a bus route. Would a Euler path and circuit be more practical, or a Hamiltonian path or circuit for a mapping algorithm?

Comment: I flagged this question as being off-topic.

Comment: Try ask here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the optimal case, you want to visit each bus stop exactly once. So, it's a Hamiltonian path by definition.